# PHP Contact Form not submitting

Tags: php, html, contact-form

Hi I've previously used this very simple php contact script with success though when I've tried implementing it on a new HTML page with the form won't submit. Can anyone see any obvious errors?
Any help would be much appreciated

Here is the html of the form:

```
<div id="formContainer">

    <form action="form.php" method="post" id="contactForm"> 
    <fieldset>

    <legend>Your details</legend>    

    <label for="name">Name *</label>
    <input type="text" id="name">

    <label for="email">Email *</label>
    <input type="email" id="email">

    <label for="tel">Telephone</label>
    <input type="tel" id="tel">

    </fieldset>

    <fieldset> 
    <legend>Tutoring</legend>

    <label for="type">Type of lesson</label>
    <select name="type" id="type">
    <option>Individual</option>
    <option>Group</option>
    </select>

    <label for="subject">Subject</label>
    <input name="subject" list="subjects" id="subject">
    <datalist id="subjects">
    <option>English</option>
    <option>Biology</option>
    <option>Geography</option>
    </datalist>

    <label for="level">Your level</label>
    <select name="level" id="level">
    <option>Beginner</option>
    <option>GCSE</option>
    <option>A-Level</option>
    <option>University</option>
    </select>

    <label for="hours">Hours/week</label>
    <input type="number" id="hours">

    <label for="info">Additional Information</label>
    <textarea name="info" id="info" rows="10"               cols="6"></textarea>


    </fieldset>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" id="sendButton">

    <input type="hidden" name="submit_check" value="1" />   
    </form>

    </div>
```

And here is the simple php script:

```
<?php 

if ($_POST["email"]<>'') { 
    $ToEmail = 'onjegolders@gmail.com'; 
    $EmailSubject = 'Site contact form '; 
    $mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
    $mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
    $mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
    $MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$_POST["name"]."<br>"; 
    $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email: ".$_POST["email"]."<br>"; 
    $MESSAGE_BODY = "Telephone: ".$_POST["tel"]."<br>";
    $MESSAGE_BODY = "Type: ".$_POST["type"]."<br>";
    $MESSAGE_BODY = "Subject: ".$_POST["subject"]."<br>";
    $MESSAGE_BODY = "Level: ".$_POST["level"]."<br>";
    $MESSAGE_BODY = "Hours required: ".$_POST["hours"]."<br>";
    $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Additional information: ".nl2br($_POST["info"])."<br>"; 
    mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Failure"); 

?> 

<html>

    <h3>Thanks for your email</h3>
    <h4>I'll get back to you as soon as possible</h4>
    <a href="index.html"><p>Click here to go back to previous page</p></a>

</html>


<?php 
} else { 
?> 

<html>Sorry, this form didn't work</html>

<?php 
}; 
?>
```

Comment: Please note that unless you're running [suhosin](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html#suhosin.mail.protect), you've got an exploitable vulnerability here; an attacker simply submits `$_POST[
email"]` with `\r\nCc: blah\r\n\r\nI Love Spam!` and you've turned your host into a spambot.

Comment: Yes I am concerned about that, the problem was that any script that had any sort of security features seemed incredibly complicated and I couldn't seem to implement them. How would I include suhosin? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with

```
if ( !empty($_POST["email"]) )
```

However you can check, what is posted in that page using:

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump( $_POST );
```

Comment: Thanks for all the replies but unfortunately changing the first if statement doesn't seem to help. Is it possible the problems is coming from the new html5 markup? This same script worked fine on another site i was using which just had a table based html4 form

Comment: No, that's not it. Whot does not work for you ? Is anything returned from `var_dump` ?

Comment: Well when i submit the form it goes straight to the else message so somewhere along the line it is not working. Sorry could you precise where I have to put your code for the var_dump? Thanks again

Comment: Thanks. i receive the following upon form submission  array(6) {
  ["type"]=>
  string(10) "Individual"
  ["subject"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["level"]=>
  string(8) "Beginner"
  ["info"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["submit"]=>
  string(4) "Send"
  ["submit_check"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
 

Sorry, this form didn't work

Comment: Because you do not have `email` field here. It's obvious that `else` statement is executed. Look at your HTML code.. you do not have `name` properties in your first 3 inputs. Name them and test it again.

Comment: Thanks. I have renamed them and the form sends! Unfortunately in the email, all I receive are the last two messages (hours and info) nothing else in the message body... Thanks again for your help

Comment: OK will do and thanks again, could you possibly see where my error is in the code as only the last two message_bodys are being sent in the email message

Comment: Just to answer my own question, though I have no idea why they are needed, I added . to all but the first message_body and now I receive everything in the mail

Answer (score 1):

Change your form.php as the following

```
    <?php 

if ($_POST["email"]<>'') { 
    $ToEmail = 'onjegolders@gmail.com'; 
    $EmailSubject = 'Site contact form '; 
    $mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
    $mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
    $mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
    $MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$_POST["name"]."<br>"; 
    $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email: ".$_POST["email"]."<br>"; 
    $MESSAGE_BODY = "Telephone: ".$_POST["tel"]."<br>";
    $MESSAGE_BODY = "Type: ".$_POST["type"]."<br>";
    $MESSAGE_BODY = "Subject: ".$_POST["subject"]."<br>";
    $MESSAGE_BODY = "Level: ".$_POST["level"]."<br>";
    $MESSAGE_BODY = "Hours required: ".$_POST["hours"]."<br>";
    $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Additional information: ".nl2br($_POST["info"])."<br>"; 
    mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Failure"); 

echo &lt;&lt;&lt;EXCERPT

<html>

    <h3>Thanks for your email</h3>
    <h4>I'll get back to you as soon as possible</h4>
    <a href="index.html"><p>Click here to go back to previous page</p></a>

</html>

EXCERPT;

} else { 


echo "<html>Sorry, this form didn't work</html>";

} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your

```
if ($_POST["email"] <> '') {
```

change that into

```
 if ($_POST["email"] != '') {
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
if(!empty($_POST["email"])){
  //your email preparation code
}
```

Insted of using this:

```
if($_POST["email" <> ''){
  //your email preparation code
}
```

The `!` basically means *not*, so the `!empty` means *not empty*

Comment: Thanks for all the replies but unfortunately changing the first if statement doesn't seem to help. Is it possible the problems is coming from the new html5 markup? This same script worked fine on another site i was using which just had a table based html4 form

Comment: Possibly, but is it actually changing pages? Or just staying on the same page when you click submit? + It may sound stupid but you may want to close of your input tags, like <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" id="sendButton" />. You've got a few tags which need closing.

Comment: I thought input tags closed with just > Have changed though, thank you. Still no joy with the form though! I should say that the new page did come up before and since adding a "name" value to my html markup, the form works and sends an email, however not all the fields show in the mail

Comment: Ok, so does the form work now then? You've selected the answer, what was wrong with it then?

Answer (score 0):

You could also just use:

```
if ($_POST["email"]) {
```

This works much like the `!= ""` or `empty()` check. PHP was incepted to handle forms well. And you can just let it probe incoming form fields. It uses some magic boolean conversion rules for strings, which most of the time will accomplish what you want.

Another advantage of this simpler style is that it eases debugging if you enable the E_ALL and E_NOTICE (=debug) error_reporting mode.