# PHP/HTML: HTML File not Sending POST data to PHP file

Tags: php, html, post

I'm trying to create a login page, with a simple form consisting of a Username, Password and Submit Button. The data from the two textfields needs to be sent to the separate PHP file so that it can query my oracle database for their validity (this bit already works with dummy data).

I'm using POST on the form, but not only is the PHP file not receiving any data, when I use code I've found online to dump the contents of the POST, the HTML file isn't even generating any.

The HTML code is as follows:

```
<html>    
  <form action="login.php" method="POST">

   <input type="text" 
        placeholder="Username:"
        name:"username"
        required
        autofocus>  

   <input type="password"   
        placeholder="Password:"
        name:"userpwd"
        required> 

   <input type="submit" 
        value="LOG IN">  

  </form>
</html>
```

And the relevant PHP code I'm using to test the POST:

```
 <?php     
   $username = htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']);
   $password = htmlspecialchars($_POST['userpwd']);

   $msg = "Username:" . $username . "\nPassword:" . $password;
   echo nl2br($msg);
 ?>
```

Nothing I've found anywhere has worked, so I'm coming here to (hopefully) find out its some silly mistake I've made and easily fixable. Cheers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Contact Form not submitting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714974/php-contact-form-not-submitting)

Comment: Use `name=` instead of `name:`, do the same for password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error happens because you are using `:` instead of `=` after `name`

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Username:" name="username" required autofocus> 
<input type="password" placeholder="Password:" name="userpwd" required>
```

Comment: AAaaaaannnndddd, that's it. I even checked for that but got tripped up looking at the Username: bit and thinking it was fine. Cheers, extra set of eyes helped a lot there.

Answer (score 0):

replace : with = in your input field after name attribute

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Username:" name="username" required autofocus>

<input type="password" placeholder="Password:" name="userpwd" required>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using colon(:) for value of "name" attribute.
Replace colon(:) with equalto(=) like below.

```
    <input type="text" 
        placeholder="Username:"
        name="username"
        required
        autofocus>  

   <input type="password"   
        placeholder="Password:"
        name:"userpwd"
        required>
```